# Is every normal subgroup of some group also a cyclic subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

I know the converse doesn't hold, but I am unable to find a counterexample. Yet I don't know how normal subgroups bring rise to a generator.

Comment: No. The alternating group $A4$ is a normal subgroup of the symmetric group $S4$, but $A4$ is not a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: But every normal subgroup of the cyclic group of order $84$ is cyclic, so I think the answer to the question is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group is a normal subgroup of itself. Therefore, any noncylic group is a counterexample. The smallest is the Klein four group.